# p paragraph ... in jquery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i'm working with limit text in my `p` tag but it work only first and third `p` tag as like this .

How to do apply to all `p` tag?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
  if('.textSec'){
  
    var p=$('.textSec p');
  var divh=$('.textSec').height();
  while ($(p).outerHeight()>divh) {
      $(p).text(function (index, text) {
          return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
      });
  }
  }
  
});
```

```css
.textSec{border:solid 1px red;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;height:120px;overflow:hidden; padding:10px;   width: 200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textSec">
      <p>LIC's New Children’s Money Back Plan is a participating non-linked money back plan. This plan is
specially designed to meet the educational, marriage and other needs of growing children through
Survival Benefits. In addition, it provides for the risk cover on the life of child during the policy term
and for number of survival benefits on surviving to the end of the specified durations. </p>
</div>

<div class="textSec">
  <p>LIC's New Money Back Plan-20 years is a participating 
                                    non-linked plan which offers an attractive combination of 
                                    protection against death throughout the term of the plan along 
                                    with the periodic payment on survival at specified durations
                                     during the term. This unique combination provides financial
                                      support for the family of the deceased policyholder any 
                                      time before maturity and lump sum amount at the time of
                                       maturity for the surviving policyholders. This plan also 
                                       takes care of liquidity needs through its loan facility. 
</p>
                                </div>

<div class="textSec">
 <p>LIC’s Anmol Jeevan - II is a protection plan which provides financial protection to the insured’s family in case of his/her unfortunate demise. 
<br >
Benefits: 
Death Benefit: In case of unfortunate death of the Life Assured during the policy 
term Sum Assured shall be payable. 
<br >Maturity Benefit: On survival to the end of the policy term, nothing shall be payable.</p>
  </div>

 <div class="textSec">
  <p>This is an immediate annuity plan, which can be purchased by paying a lump sum amount.
                                     This plan provides for 
                                    annuity payments of a stated amount throughout the life time of the annuitant. 
Various options are available for the type and mode of payment of annuities.  <br />
Premium in this plan is to be paid in a lump sum. Annuity may be paid either at 
monthly, quarterly, half yearly or yearly intervals. Annuitant may choose any mode of payment of annuity.</p>
 </div>

<div class="textSec">
  <p>LIC's Jeevan Arogya is a unique non-participating 
                                    non-linked plan which provides health insurance cover 
                                    against certain specified health risks and provides you 
                                    with timely support in case of medical emergencies and helps
                                     you and your family remain financially independent in difficult
                                      times. Health has been a major concern on everybody’s mind, 
                                      including yours. In these days of skyrocketing medical expenses,
                                       when a family member is ill, it is a traumatic time for the rest
                                        of the family. As a caring person, you do not want to let any
                                         unfortunate incident to affect your plans for you and your 
                                         family. So why let any medical emergencies shatter your peace 
                                         of mind. </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: `p` will be a collection of elements - your code is treating p like it is a single element. I would expect to see a `.each` to iterate through the paragraphs, working on each one individually, rather than what this code does, which, to be honest, I'm surprised works at all

Comment: Not really related to your question, but `if('.textSec')` will always evaluate to true. Any non-empty string will evaluate to true in an `if`. I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve with that, so can't say what it should be, but as it currently is, it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you should be setting the height for each paragraph individually and not via the first element.

```
var p = $('.textSec p');  //grabs all of the paragraphs
var divh=$('.textSec').height();  //we read the height of the first texxtSec element
p.each( function () {  //loop over the paragraphs
   var para = $(this); //current paragraph
   while (para.outerHeight()>divh) {  //loop until the height condition is met
       para.text(function (index, text) {
           return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');   
       });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`var p = $('.textsec').find('p')` or `var p = $('.textsec').children('p')` depending on your nested elements.

Comment: `var p=$('.textSec p')` (which is what the questioner currently has) and `var p = $('.textsec').find('p')` return the same thing.